# Dplyr mutate pipe combine multiple columns of adjusted p values

Tags: r, dplyr

R learner here!

I have a data.frame like this:

```
x = data.frame(genes = c("a", "b", "c"),
           pval1 = c(0.0003, NA, NA),
           pval2 = c(0.008, NA, 0.2),
           pval3 = c(0.0009, 0.000007, 0.000001) )
```

I want to combine the p value columns with NA values row-wise using Fisher's (or other suitable stat) and create a new column. How can I do this within a dplyr pipe?

I have done the following, but its obviously not working!

```
out_x = x %>% dplyr::mutate(comb_p_val = ezlimma::combine_pvalues(., p.cols = "pval" ))
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Combine how? Can you provide a desired output?

Comment: If I get it right, you could use Base R only.
`x$comb_p_val <- paste(x$pval1,x$pval2,x$pval3)`
This creates a new column `comb_p_val` in the dataframe `x` with all the values of the pvalue-columns per row combined.

Comment: It seems `ezlimma::combine_pvalues` shouldn't be used with mutate but instead takes the table as an argument based on the documentation here: https://rdrr.io/github/jdreyf/ezlimma/man/combine_pvalues.html

I couldn't get it to install so I am not sure but I think something like
`ezlimma::combine_pvalues(x, p.cols = "pval")` should work